# Cannot get a service in my controller symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem in my controller when I want to get a sevice that I create, everything work well when I'm in localhost, but when I put the website in my server I get the problem.

Here is the line that make the error in my controller:

```
$myService = $this->get('Acme_test.service');
```

The `services.yml`:

```
services:
    Acme_test.service:
        class: Acme\testBundle\Services\Testservice
        arguments: [%folder%, @service_container]
```

And the error:

```
ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "Testservice" from namespace "Acme\TestBundle\Services" in /home/www/acme/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 736. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?
```

I tried to clear the cache, still having the same error !!

Comment: Maybe typo in `testBundle` - `TestBundle`? Additionally you could clear cache manually: `rm -rf app/cache/*`. And please remember about `--env=prod` on your serwer.

Comment: Let me guess: localhost is Windows, your server is linux.  As @NHG suggested, testBundle is probably the issue.

Comment: thanks for the answers, no the typo is not the problem, because I just changed it when I want to write it here :) and yes localhost is windows for me and my server is linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set **nested** your service to the `services` node in the `services.yml` file like:

```
services:
    acme_test.service:
        class: Acme\TestBundle\Service\TestService
        arguments: [%folder%, @service_container]
```

And I think better write service name in lowercase. And then get service in controller like:

```
$myService = $this->get('acme_test.service');
```

**NOTE:** I think that you meant `TestBundle` and `TestService` names in *camelCase*

**NOTE2:** And commonly services dir name is `Service`, so check your namespace, it need to be `Acme\TestBundle\Service`, class name need to be `TestService` and  file `Acme\TestBundle\Service\TestService.php` must exists.

**NOTE3:** After all recommendations and modifications manually clear cache dir.

Comment: Thanks, I did all the recommandations still having the same error, I cleared the cache and also remove the folders manually from the cache, I repeat I have no problem in my localhost the problem come when I upload the website and test it in the dev mode. (for the nested part, it is nested just when I copied the code here it was not nested anymore)

Comment: I understand that when you upload the website and test it in the dev mode - you have the error, but when you test it in prod, it work, right?

Comment: And at what version of PHP do you try to run website when upload it?

Comment: Thanks I just forgot to use the CamelCase in my services.yml but still don't know why it was working in the localhost :) anywhere, thank you! in the prod mode I have an empty page why ?

Comment: in the prod mode I have a blank page ?!! any idea

Comment: You need to set `error_reporting = E_ALL` in your `php.ini` file to see the error

Comment: I think you need to ask another question for this